# XSL: xsl:if test not working and calculate sum

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0

For the below simplified transformation sheet, I'd like to add the following functions:

1. For "Turnover 2019" and "Turnover 2020" I'd like to get the values below 1mio in a red badge and over 1mio in a green badge. I tried to implement this for "Turnover 2019", however I just get a blank output. The problem seems to be with the `<xsl:if test="...">`-part, as I do get the correct value if I just enter `<xsl:value-of select="key('keyToCreditcard', id)/turnover_2019"/>` (see "Turnover 2020").
2. For "Total Turnover" I need to sum up the values of "Turnover 2019" and "Turnover 2020". How do I do that?

**XSL**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="keyToPerson" match="person" use="id"/>
  <xsl:key name="keyToCreditcard" match="creditcard" use="cardowner"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="data/persons/person">
      <xsl:if test="turnoverYear1 &lt; 1000000">
        <span class="badge bg-warning mx-2"><xsl:value-of select="key('keyToCreditcard', id)/turnoverYear1"/></span>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="turnoverYear1 &gt; 999999.99">
        <span class="badge bg-danger mx-2"><xsl:value-of select="key('keyToCreditcard', id)/turnoverYear1"/></span>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="key('keyToCreditcard', id)/turnoverYear2"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Input**:

```
<data>
 <persons>
   <person>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>Jeramie Bischoff</name>
      <city>Luzern</city>
      <birthdate>04/16/1951</birthdate>
    </person>
  </persons>
  <creditcards>
    <creditcard>
      <id>1</id>
      <cardtype>Visa</cardtype>
      <cardnumber>4041592612048990</cardnumber>
      <turnoverYear1>952411.33</turnoverYear1>
      <turnoverYear2>6135840.0</turnoverYear2>
      <cardowner>1</cardowner>
  </creditcard>
 </creditcards>
</data>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Name:Jeramie Bischoff
City: Luzern
birthdate: 04/16/1951

Card Type: Visa
Card Number: 4041592612048990
Turnover 2019: 952411.33
Turnover 2020: 6135840.0
Total Turnover: 7088251.33
```

Comment: There is no way to answer this without seeing the XML you are working with.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] incl. an input and the expected output (as code).

Comment: Also, you apparently have elements called `<turnover_2019>` and `<turnover_2020>`. That's a bad idea. If you can do anything about that, change it. It makes life *much* harder to have elements that carry data in their names. Use something like `<turnover year="2019">` instead.

Comment: Does 1mio mean 100000?

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs, I have now amended this accordingly.

Comment: Your example is ambiguous, because a `person` can own more that one `creditcard`- and it's not clear whether you want to summarize them separately or together. It is also not clear how `turnoverYear1` gets translated to `Turnover 2019`. Keep in mind that  XSLT 1.0 has no way to get the current date on its own. I don't suppose you want to rewrite the XSLT every year - so perhaps you should look for a way to pass that information to the stylesheet at runtime or use an extension function, if your processor supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample XML, a good approach would be to split things up into multiple templates.

One to handle creating the basic HTML document structure (`match="/"`), one to handle `<person>` elements, one to handle the turnover badges, and so on. In general it's beneficial to prefer `<xsl:apply-templates>` over cramming everything into a single template with a bunch of nested `<xsl:for-each>`.

Since you have an `<xsl:key>` that links person IDs to credit cards, use that to fetch the `<creditcard>` into a variable (`$cc`) and work with it.

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
<xsl:key name="keyToCreditcard" match="creditcard" use="cardowner"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <!-- ... -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="data/persons/person" />
    <!-- ... -->
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person">
  <div class="person">
    <xsl:variable name="cc" select="key('keyToCreditcard', id)" />
    <!-- your question #1 -->
    <div>
      <xsl:text>Turnover 2019: </xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$cc/turnoverYear1" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <xsl:text>Turnover 2020: </xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$cc/turnoverYear2" />
    </div>
    <!-- your question #2 -->
    <div>
      <xsl:text>Total Turnover: </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$cc/turnoverYear1 + $cc/turnoverYear2" />
    </div>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="turnoverYear1|turnoverYear2">
  <span>
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:text>badge mx-2 </xsl:text>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=". &lt; 1000000">bg-warning</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test=". &lt; 99999.99">bg-danger</xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </span>
</xsl:template>
```

which results in

```
<html>
  <div class="person">
    <div>Turnover 2019: <span class="badge mx-2 bg-warning">952411.33</span></div>
    <div>Turnover 2020: <span class="badge mx-2">6135840.0</span></div>
    <div>Total Turnover: 7088251.33</div>
  </div>
</html>
```

---

Because the year numbers and XML element names are a moving target in your XML, you would have to keep adjusting the XSLT code every year. That's completely unnecessary. It's a lot smarter to keep the year out of the XML element names. Move it into an attribute:

```
<creditcards>
  <creditcard>
    <id>1</id>
    <cardtype>Visa</cardtype>
    <cardnumber>4041592612048990</cardnumber>
    <turnover year="2019">952411.33</turnover>
    <turnover year="2020">6135840.0</turnover>
    <cardowner>1</cardowner>
  </creditcard>
</creditcards>
```

With a `<creditcard>` setup like this, the XSLT code gets more generic.

```
<xsl:template match="person">
  <div class="person">
    <xsl:variable name="cc" select="key('keyToCreditcard', id)" />
    <!-- your question #1 -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$cc/turnover" />
    <!-- your question #2 -->
    <div>
      <xsl:text>Total Turnover: </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="sum($cc/turnover)" />
    </div>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="turnover">
  <div>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Turnover ', @year, ': ')" />
    <span>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:text>badge mx-2 </xsl:text>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test=". &lt; 1000000">bg-warning</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test=". &lt; 99999.99">bg-danger</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </span>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @Anja Good to hear. But also think about all the comments you got. For example, plan for what happens when there is more than one creditcard per person.